# Viewing project on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby. I can view my project on browser when I write `ruby script/server` otherwise I can't view my project on localhost.

What I have to do to view my project always on browser?

Comment: how about taking a screenshot? :)

Comment: You should really explain your problem better. Are you using rails?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ruby on rails for the first time . Your answer is detached(deamon) mode .
Make sure your ruby version is more then 1.8.6 and rails version is less then 3.x.x 
Script is

`ruby script/server -d`

And to know more

`ruby script/server --help`

Answer (score 0):

When you use your application (using a browser) the application's code is run on a web server that receives the requests, execute the right code and respond to the user.

Now, rails provide a simple web server that you can run with `rails server` and you can use to test and develop your application. This web server is run on your machine and when you go to `http://localhost:3000/` it's that local web server that responds.

If you want to access your application you need a webserver running. If you want to access your application anytime from everywhere the application must be in a server accessible from everywhere but you first need to deploy your application.